# Is there an easy way to create a link to past questions?

Tags: feature-request

When I refer to past questions, I find it cumbersome to create a viewer-friendly link to it, i.e. the text title with the link to the question. I often feel lazy and just put http://japanese.stackexchange.com.... link copied from 'Share' in the question.

I guess this is not specific to this SE, but is there an easy way to create links from existing questions?

To be concrete, what I'm expecting is a functionality such that when I click something on an existing question, text like `[the title of the question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/...)`  is copied to the clipboard.

Comment: チャットでこのリンクを貼ってくれた人がいたので、コピーして貼りますね：https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366938/include-comment-markdown-formatting-in-share-link

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who are wondering the same, I ended up using [tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) with the following userscript.

- https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper